# Correlated sub query of movie

Tags: sql

Table `Movie(Title,year,director,length)`

Find movies whose titles appears more than once (different years)

```
Select Distinct title 
From Movie as x
where year <> any
              (Select year 
               from movie
               where title = x.title);
```

I don't understand this sql code, anyone can explain?

Comment: I don't understand it either.  I'd use a totally different approach.

Comment: that code won't run. impossible to understand a query that is not written in a logical way.

Comment: It is in my notes though, i dont understand, any other alternative solutions to this question

Comment: The query is correct. Just hard to explain.

Comment: From my understanding, this is a correlated sub-query. correct me if i am wrong. It will have a copy of the movie table as x and it queries by looking row by row, starting from the first row, it scans in x for the same title then select that year and excludes it. From here on i am clueless.. anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18030):

**9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)**

> expression operator ANY (array expression)
> expression operator SOME (array expression)
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is "true" if any true result is obtained. The result is "false" if no true result is found (including the case where the array has zero elements).
>
> If the array expression yields a null array, the result of ANY will be null. If the left-hand expression yields null, the result of ANY is ordinarily null (though a non-strict comparison operator could possibly yield a different result). Also, if the right-hand array contains any null elements and no true comparison result is obtained, the result of ANY will be null, not false (again, assuming a strict comparison operator). This is in accordance with SQL's normal rules for Boolean combinations of null values.
>
> SOME is a synonym for ANY.

So basically if any of the predicates formed by using the array, then the whole expression evaluates to true:

With some example data

```
     Title      | Year
----------------+--------
Point Break     | 1991
The Italian Job | 1969
The Italian Job | 2003
```

For the Italian Job your where clause will be

```
WHERE Year <> 1969
OR Year <> 2003
```

For each record this will evaluate to true since one of the years will be different each time. For Point Break the where clause will be

```
WHERE Year <> 1991
```

This will not return true so the record is not returned.

So your query is asking for a distinct list of film titles where another film exists with the same title and a different year.

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d083a/4)**

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about `where year <> any`:

The sub query will get you all years one title appears. For every row (`title`), check if there is **any other** year(s) that title appears which is different `<>` from current year.

1. If TRUE, that title appears more than once (in different years). Return that title.
2. If FALSE, that title appears only once.

Answer (score 0):

Does this query help?

```
select * from 
  (select *,
    (select count(1)
     from movie m2
     where m2.title = m.title and m2.year <> m.year) as MovieCount
   from movie m) as z
where z.MovieCount > 0
```

Comment: I hope this helps you figure out your what you need.
-Thomas
RosSQL.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0):

That year<> ANY (...) does not convince me at all.

As an alternative, I'd use something like:

```
SELECT Title
FROM Movie
GROUP BY Title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year)>1
```